# Are the positive qualities of enlightenment ultimate or conventional realities?

Tags: mahayana, nirvana

Are the positive qualities of enlightenment ultimate or conventional realities?

These [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(Buddhism)#Positive_language)

> permanence, bliss, personality, purity.

If they are ultimately the case, can they be directly seen?

Comment: Do you mean "are they ultimate truths?" or do you mean "do they exist ultimately?"

Answer (score 1):

Enlightened qualities are ultimate. One's mind is innately ultimate ie. enlightened.

A highly achieved buddhist practitioner often likens the enlightened mind with the clear blue sky.

Often clouds (defilements) obscure the clear blue sky and the clear sky cannot be seen. In other words, without the clouds, the clear blue sky (the ultimate) can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

'Ultimate realities' (*paramattha dhamma*) in original Pali Buddhism means things that are always true. For example, that for suffering to occur, there must be craving & attachment as causes, is an ultimate reality. Suffering cannot occur without craving & attachment.

Conversely, the general truth that good karma leads to good results & bad karma leads to bad results is not an ultimate reality because this is not always the case. For example, good karma (eg. loving one's family) had lead to suffering (eg. if your family die) & bad karma (eg. hurting another person) can lead to enlightenment (since one learns to never perform that action again).

Convention realities can also refer to ideas such as 'man', 'woman', 'hot', 'cold', 'American', 'Chinese', etc, which are not always 100% or inherently true or fixed.

Therefore, full enlightenment (rather than partial enlightenment) is always permanent, blissful & pure for the entire lifetime of an enlightened being. This is an ultimate truth, which, naturally, can be directly seen by the fully enlightened being.

As for 'personality' or 'self', this is not an ultimate reality in Buddhism.

However, if 'personality' is taken to mean 'character' or 'mental qualities', yes, the virtuous & enlightened character of a fully enlightened being will have a permanent quality.

When the Buddha was old, it is reported he said:

> *I am now old, aged, burdened with years, advanced in life and come to the last stage: my years have turned eighty... Sariputta, even if you
>   have to carry me about on a bed, still there will be no change in the
>   lucidity of the Tathagata's wisdom.*
>
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.012.ntbb.html

Comment: in what way is full enlightenment not a self if it is permanent?

Comment: why would enlightenment be a 'self'? since when was 'permanence' as 'self'? imagine if the universe or space was permanent? would the universe or space be a 'self'? the word 'self' refers to ideas of "I", "me" & "mine". enlightenment, nirvana, space, the universe, a block of long lasting concrete, do not have any ideas of "I", "me" & "mine". there was once an Indian logician named Nargajuna, who equated 'sunnata' with 'conditionality'. Nargajuna was not the Buddha. The Buddha was not Nargajuna. The Buddha taught nirvana was unconditioned, permanent & not-self.

Comment: i dunno, all those terms (i me and mine) sound like totally viable conventional designators, which, if picking out something permanent, would be very much like a "self". so, those terms, as much as what they designate, seem like they break down under scrutiny, at least without supporting them with a further ontological quality, like permanence

Comment: What you are posting is not related to Buddhism, which is about suffering & the end of suffering. The unconditioned state, empty of craving & self-view, is permanent but is not a 'self'. How can something, 100% devoid of 'self', be a 'self'? 'Not-self' is not actually dependent on impermanence. The physical body has no self in it. The physical body, when seen as merely the physical body, is empty of self. That is why it was taught 'form is void; void is form'. Impermanence may demonstrate  'not-self' but this is just a beginners introduction. The only self that exists is a mental construction.

Comment: 'Ontological' is a term from Western philosophy. It is unrelated to Buddhism. The Buddha taught that talk about whether 'things exist or not' is 'animal talk'. Nargajuna talked about whether things exist or not, which is not Buddhism, such as claiming a tree or dog has no inherent existence. The Buddha did not care about whether trees exist or not. The Buddha was only concerned with not clinging to a tree as 'me' & 'mine'. The Buddha was also concerned with what is permanent happiness (Nirvana).

Comment: to say that the Nagarjuna did not teach buddhism is just wrong

Comment: dare i ask where the buddha says that talking about existence is "animal talk"? there are a number of suttas where he uses that term, including in the discussion of self (it does not exist). it could be that these are basic or introductory discourses, but that doesn't mean they're not true. you seem to be reducing buddhism to ethics and liberation, i find that misleading

Comment: it seems true that buddhism also says how things are, e.g. in the theory of dependent origination. it does make sense, i think, to ask what "self" means, beyond the harm of attachment

Comment: really no point in continuing this discussion since Buddha & Nargajuna are very different. The Buddha was concerned with the existence of the self-delusion but not concerned with the existence of the planet earth. Buddha used the term 'dependent origination' to refer to 12 conditions leading to suffering where as Nargajuna used dependent origination to describe how 2 parts oxygen 1 part hydrogen make water.

Comment: ok, millions of buddhists are practicing a fake religion

Comment: @user3293056 You can certainly ask what 'self' means, but if you are attached to a particular answer or type of answer, it becomes a "vexing question". You can experience this for yourself. Ultimately, you have to find and evaluate your own answers. No one else can provide them to you ready-made.